# ImportError: No module named observers after installed watchdog

Tags: python, importerror, watchdog

Im trying to run [official watchdog simple example](http://packages.python.org/watchdog/quickstart.html#a-simple-example) after installing the `watchdog` module using pip: `pip install watchdog`, and i get an error:

```
from watchdog.observers import Observer
ImportError: No module named observers
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: it seems that it was too short question before...

Comment: Did watchdog installation complete succesflly. Can you try "import watchdog" in interactive Python interpreter.

Comment: And what is the exact Python environment / command you used to install watchdog? Did you install it in system libraries?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: OP already said they used PIP

Comment: pip install itself should not do anything unless you run it as a root or have virtualenv activated. Also the installation log is missing and the author's installation may simply have failed.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: What are you talking about? pip is not bound to virtualenv, nor is it bound to being run as root. If your python site-packages isn't locked down, it works just fine. And I don't know why you got a +1 for that statement

Comment: FWIW, I just used `pip install watchdog` to install it on my OS X system (not being root or using virtualenv), and everything worked as it should.

Comment: @DSM: Exactly. That statement by Mikko is making presumptions about the permissions of your python installation and your platform.

Comment: oh, guys, sorry for this alarm, it is caused that named my file 'watchdog.py', my bad. thanks a lot:)

Comment: @SagarHatekar I would like, but I cant: 'Uncaught TypeError: Property 'confirm' of object [object Window] is not a function importerror-no-module-named-observers-after-installed-watchdog:603
(anonymous function) importerror-no-module-named-observers-after-installed-watchdog:603
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.i jquery.min.js:3
' - when I click "Answer your Question"

Comment: @scythargon Just copy and paste the following text in your answer. "I figured the cause for the ImportError issue. My module name was the same as the module I was trying to import. Renaming my module to something else other than watchdog or observers resolved this issue. Thanks all for your help!"

Comment: @SagarHatekar thanks a lot, e. are you kidding? I said - there are JavaScript error when I press "Answer Your Question" in the bottom of the page.

Comment: @scythargon Exactly! There's something funny in that comment which SO doesn't like! :)

Comment: Had the same problem, thanks. For others also needed to manually delete my "watchdog.pyc" before it would work

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I figured the cause for the ImportError issue. My module name was the same as the module I was trying to import. Renaming my module to something else other than watchdog or observers resolved this issue. Thanks all for your help!